# Al hamichya in different location when continued eating rice but started with cake

Tags: halacha, bentching, mezonot-beracha, birkat-meeyn-shalosh, shinuy-deviation

If someone start eating cake in one location he/she can make על המחיה in a totally different location (from which the first cannot be seen) if one continues eating there.

Does the food that is continued eating have to be from the 5 grains - חמשת מיני דגן, or can it be anything? What about rice, for example, the person ate cake in one house and then continued eating rice in another house?

Assume that this person had in mind to continue eating in the other location when making the first Mezonos.

Comment: See siman 178:2 that he would definitely not need a bracha rishona even on water in such a case, however he would have to return to make the bracha achrona if all he did was drink water. So in your case, if he’s not eating anything that requires Al hamichya in the new place, why wouldn’t he have to go back to his original place to make the Al hamichya?